# How to re-engineer an Ui-File from a given QWidget instance

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, reverse-engineering

Does anybody know if the Qt Toolkit provides a way to generate Ui Files from a given QWidget instance?
Speaking in pseudo-code, I'm looking for something like this:

```
//setup widget
QWidget* pMyWidget=new QWidget(...);

//fill widget with life
pMyWidget->layout()->addWidget(new QLabel(...));
...

//finally write a Ui file:
pMyWidget->exportToUiFile(QString("/some/path/to/filename.ui"));
```

Alternatively: does somebody know a tool capable of doing this?
Thx in advance,
Axel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QFormBuilder::save()` from the `QtDesigner` module.

Comment: Although the decoded .ui file looks a little bit strange, when evaluating it in the designer, that was exactly what I was looking for!